# Laravel Fortify - Send back User model after register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-fortify

I am using Laravel Fortify for authentication with a single page React app. I am running into an issue where when I create a new user using Fortify's `POST /register` route its just returning a response of `""`. I am wanting this `POST /register` route to return the User model that was created. Right now in my `FortifyServiceProvider.php` I have the following code:

```
$this->app->instance(RegisterResponse::class, new class implements RegisterResponse {
  public function toResponse($request) {
    // This doesn't give access to the User model created, just the request params
  }
});
```

But this doesn't give me access to the user model that was created with the register route. Does anyone know how I can send back the User model when using Fortify's baked in register route?